# Understanding the scipy error: "error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, odeint

I am trying to solve the ODE dc/dt=-k*c^alpha, where k and alpha are the parameters to be fit, and c is the solution at time t, using the scipy library. I get the error **"error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."** from my code. I have seen a [similar question posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474275/scipy-curve-fit-error-result-from-function-call-is-not-a-proper-array-of-float), and they used np.ravel() on the 'def func' function output. I tried this but got the **error: 'int' object has no attribute ravel'**. I've reverted to my original code which has the error as previous. How could I fix my code? Possible also to explain what the problem is?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the ODE function
def ode_func(c, t, k, alpha):
    return -k*c**alpha

# Define the initial condition and time points
c0 = 1.73
t = np.linspace(1, 50, 1000)

# Solve the ODE using scipy's odeint function
c_true = odeint(ode_func, c0, t, args=(2, 2))

# Add some noise to the true solution
np.random.seed(0)
c_noisy = c_true + 0.1 * np.random.randn(*c_true.shape)

# Use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit the noisy data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(ode_func, t, c_noisy)

plt.plot(t, odeint(ode_func, c0, t, args=(popt[0], popt[1])), 'r-', label='Fitted solution')

#plotting the noisy solution
plt.plot(t, c_noisy, 'o', label='Noisy solution')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Error detail

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 2
      1 # Use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit the noisy data
----> 2 popt, pcov = curve_fit(ode_func, t, c_noisy)     

File c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:859, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, full_output, **kwargs)
    856 if ydata.size != 1 and n > ydata.size:
    857     raise TypeError(f"The number of func parameters={n} must not"
    858                     f" exceed the number of data points={ydata.size}")
--> 859 res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    860 popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    861 ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

File c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:426, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    424     if maxfev == 0:
    425         maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 426     retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    427                              gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    428 else:
    429     if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: The problem is pretty clear from the message.  Your function is returning an integer, and it needs to be a float.  Just do `return float(-k*c**alpha)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts - thanks for this. When I do this I now get the error: "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" from the function. I'm coming more from the science background so still building my coding intuition.

Comment: Your original code works for me.  What is `c_noisy`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Realised the definition of `c_noisy` was missing. Just added in. Is it still running for you?

Comment: Please **read the relevant documentation** and then try to answer the following questions as best you can: 1) Where the code says `def ode_func(c, t, k, alpha):`, what do you think this means? 2) When you call `curve_fit`, how do you expect for it to make use of `ode_func`? In particular: when `ode_func` is called, what do you think the values of `c`, `t`, `k` and `alpha` will look like? What will be their *types*? 3) What should be the type of the value returned from `ode_func`, in order for `curve_fit` to be able to use it properly?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `def ode_func(c, t, k, alpha):` This is a function taking c,t,k, and alpha as inputs **in that order**. When called it returns `-k*c**alpha`. According to the docs, `curve_fit` should take the function **with the independent variable first**.. This is not the case in the above code as the dependent variable c is first.  I have rearranged the function order on `ode_func`, and I have used 'tfirst' as an argument to `odeint` to ensure it takes this into account (independent variable first).  Now I've confirmed `t` is NDArray but `c_noise` isn't (incorrectly). Is this correct so far?

Comment: My suggestion is to try debugging *inside `ode_func`, for example by using `print` calls or a debugger in order to *check* what has been passed and what will be returned. The error message complains that what got returned is not an array (meaning, Numpy array, not a list) of floats, right? So - what do you get instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe it was just inheriting the values of the input parameters as far as I can tell. When I  manually passed values into `ode_func` it returned a float type. So I used `numpy.ndarray` on the function output which changes it into an array. However, it still doesn't run and I have the same error. I don't quite understand what a proper array of floats means. Should the numpy array contain floats within it?

Comment: An array of floats means a Numpy array which has a `dtype` of `float`, i.e., which contains floats. When your function is called, it will be passed an array of X values and some constants, and your function computes the corresponding array of Y values. The library will iterate this, trying different values for the constants, to fit the result to the noisy data.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am stuck and a bit tired. I will try troubleshooting later. Thanks for your assistance.